# "$pull" doesn't delete the embedded documents of mongoose array

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, embedded-documents

My mongo schema is as below:

```
resourceId: {
        type: String,
    },

    resourceName: {
        type: String,
    },

    dateAndValue: [
        {
            date: { type: Date },
            value: { type: Number },
        },
    ],
```

Once data is added to the "dateAndValue" array, I want to remove all objects in the array that includes '0' as the value. This is the code I used for it but it doesn't seem to work:

```
await QuantumResourcesManpowerAdmin.updateMany(
    { resourceId: qrmaRecord.resourceId },
    {
        $pull: {
            dateAndValue: {
                $elemMatch: { value: 0 },
            },
        },
    },
    { multi: true }
);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the answer, $elemMatch should be removed from the above code. So,

```
await QuantumResourcesManpowerAdmin.update(
    { resourceId: qrmaRecord.resourceId },
    {
        $pull: {
            dateAndValue: {
                value: 0,
            },
        },
    },
    { safe: true, multi: true }
);
```

would work without any issue